# Adding animation to UIButton between states

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a button with two states (i toggle the button using the "selected" state). I would like to animate the transition between the states when user clicks on the button.

I have a list of images that form the animation - what would be the logic to add the animations to the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subclass UIButton, override `setSelected` method this way:

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected{
    self.enabled = NO; // disable btn until animation finished
    [self setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    NSArray *imageNames;

    // hardcoded frames sequences is for clarity ofcourse =)
    if (selected){
        // direct frames sequence
        imageNames = @[@"normalBG", @"frame0", @"frame1", @"frame2", @"selectedBG"];
    } else {
        // reversed frames sequence
        imageNames = @[@"selectedBG", @"frame2", @"frame1", @"frame0", @"normalBG"];
    }
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = (float)imageNames.count/YOUR_ANIMATION_FPS;

    NSMutableArray *imageBuffer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageNames.count];
    NSMutableArray *timeBuffer = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageNames.count];

    [imageNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [imageBuffer addObject:(__bridge id)[UIImage imageNamed:name].CGImage];
        [timeBuffer addObject:@( (float)(idx)/(imageNames.count-1) )];
    }];

    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithArray:imageBuffer];
    NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithArray:timeBuffer];
    imageBuffer = nil;
    timeBuffer = nil;


    CAKeyframeAnimation *framesAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    framesAnimation.values = images;
    framesAnimation.keyTimes = times;
    framesAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear;
    framesAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    framesAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    framesAnimation.duration = animationDuration;


    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [super setSelected:selected];
        if (selected){
            [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBG"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [self setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            [self setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalBG"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        self.enabled = YES;
    }];
    [self.layer addAnimation:framesAnimation forKey:@"contents"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

don't forget to set the initial background image, i.e. `[self setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalBG"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];` in button's `init` method